# Использовать iframe, чтобы показать другой сайт

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, iframe

Всем привет. Помогите новичку разобраться. Есть сайт написан на wordpress. Я хочу его использовать на определенном домене, но условие пользования таким доменом это использование их самописной CMS. Уж очень не хочется адаптировать под их "кривулю". Есть ли возможность (через iframe например) на главной странице открыть другой сайт на другом хостинге? Заранее спасибо, и извините за идиотский вопрос.

Comment: Подходит ли вам JavaScript код `window.location = "URL другого сайта";`?

Comment: И не забанят ли вас из-за этого на данном домене?

Comment: Понятия не имею на самом деле. Я думаю не должны. Нужно узнать. Беглый поиск по документации не запрещает

Comment: @PeterOlson а как его использовать? 
<code>
<html>
<div>
<script>
function newDoc() {
    window.location.assign("http://www.мойсайт.com")
}
</script>
</div>
 </html></code>
Как то так?

Comment: А хостинг поменять?

Comment: @borodatych не вариант, сайт для школы, организация дает домены и хостинг только под свою cms, домен отдавать они не хотят, другую cms тоже не хотят. Единственный, как мне кажется костыль это открыть сайт в сайте

Comment: Как то сложно... Надо учесть все факторы, все взвесить. Насколько нужно старое имя? Зарегайте новое. Какая посещаемость? Редирект на новый домен... Домен нельзя завернуть на другой хост? Бред какой то. Садик завязан на организации? Или организация раньше вела этот сайт? Если вела, то надо выяснить за кем права.